# Dessazonalizar dados da PIM com o R

Tags: r, modelagem, séries-temporais

vou começar falando que sou quase analfabeto em programação então tenham um pouco de paciência.

Estou tentando dessazonalizar a série histórica da PIM pelo r conforme as instruções do IBGE, pra isso tô usando o pacote X13. O problema é que mesmo rodando  conforme as instruções, meu resultado nunca bate com o do IBGE, exemplo da programação:

```
fumob <-read.csv2("fumo.csv") #SEMPRE VERIFICAR SE A SEPARAÇÃO É PONTO OU VIRGULA
fumo.ts<-ts(fumob,start=c(2002,1),freq=12) #A BASE ORIGINAL NÃO PODE TER DATAS
fumo.ts

fumosa <- seas(x = fumo.ts, arima.model = "(1 0 0)(0 1 1)", transform.function = "none",
               automdl = NULL, regression.aictest = NULL)
```

No caso a base foi a de "Produtos de Fumo" que o IBGE específica somente um modelo ARIMA  (1 0 0)(0 1 1) e mais nenhum outro detalhe. Já tentei colocar e tirar os Trading Days, de jeito nenhum o resultado fica próximo.

Alguém já mexeu com essas dessazonalizações pelo r? Conseguiria me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Em Produtos de Fumo, o tipo de decomposição que aparece na nota metodológica é "Multiplicativa", entao o transform.function é "log". Além disso, tem que acrescentar o parâmetro "outlier.types = "all"".